# IAM Policy to restrict users from launching EC2 instances into a particular VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, vpc

I am trying to use this policy to restrict users from launching any instances into the specified VPC. However, I am still able to launch instances! Why is this policy not working? Obviously, the resource Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:::vpc//vpc-xyz has actual values in my production template

```
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "ec2:Run*",
            "ec2:Terminate*",
            "ec2:Cancel*",
            "ec2:Create*",
            "ec2:Delete*",
            "ec2:Modify*",
            "ec2:Start*",
            "ec2:Stop*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT-ID>:vpc/<VPC-ID>/vpc-xyz",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Sid": "DenyInstanceActionsForVPC"
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/Project": [
                    "Cloud Services",
                    "MDH",
                    "Shine"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Action": [
            "ec2:Run*",
            "ec2:Terminate*",
            "ec2:Cancel*",
            "ec2:Create*",
            "ec2:Delete*",
            "ec2:Modify*",
            "ec2:Start*",
            "ec2:Stop*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Sid": "DenyInstanceActionsForCStaggedResources"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The first item. You have no ALLOW in your policy. Therefore you should not be able to do anything. Solve this problem first.

Next modify your first statement to look like this:

```
{
    "Sid": "DenyInstanceActionsForVPC",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": [
        "ec2:Run*",
        "ec2:Terminate*",
        "ec2:Cancel*",
        "ec2:Create*",
        "ec2:Delete*",
        "ec2:Modify*",
        "ec2:Start*",
        "ec2:Stop*"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:subnet/*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
           "ec2:vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTNUMBER:vpc/VPC-ID"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks John. I do have an allow policy which is working fine I just did not include it in the problem summary. I have tried your solution and used the VPC-ID as a condition and the subnet arn for the Resource as you suggested and it worked. Cheers